# Save a custom pivot table style EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, templates

I went to the  effort of creating a custom pivot table design, to match my companies work colours.

**I'm looking for a way to save a custom table style (not Workbook) as a template, so it can be used in other workbooks.**

I have done this with several charts, which can then be used again, so was hoping it is also possible with a Pivot Table .

I have found a work around for this, I can copy the original created template and paste it into a new workbook, the design is then available to use, but surely there must be a way of saving the actual design ?!

Comment: Pivot tables and charts can be [saved as an Excel template](http://www.exceltutorials.net/how-to-create-a-template-from-an-existing-pivot-table-and-chart-to-use-with-a-new-set-of-data.html) file (.xlt).  Then you open the template, enter new data, and save the resulting file as .xlsx.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: You could also define the style in code. Then run your VBA macro to insert the table with your styling in to active sheet. Like this: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/9/27/vba-guide-excel-pivot-tables

Answer (score 2):

There is, but it ain't pretty:

1. Copy a Table/PivotTable that uses the new Table Style into a new
   blank workbook.
2. Setting that Table/PivotTable Style as the Default Style
3. Delete that Table/PivotTable
4. Save the workbook as an Excel Template in the Startup folder, so
   that Excel will use this workbook – and your beautifew new Custom
   Table/PivotTable Style – as a template whenever you create a new
   document.

Read more at my blogpost at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/02/27/custom-table-styles/

Answer (score 0):

Excel provides no way of transferring custom pivot table styles,
so transferring a custom style to new documents is difficult if it is
not already included in the template as described in the
[answer by @jeffreyweir](https://superuser.com/a/1267017/8672).

If you wish to transfer a custom style without using a document template,
this is done as follows.

**Excel version from before 2016**

1. In any workbook containing the custom style, select any cell in the
   pivot table that has that custom style applied.
2. On the Ribbon's Options tab, in the Actions group, click Select, and then click Entire PivotTable
3. On the Ribbon's Home tab, click Copy.
4. Switch to the new workbook.
5. Select a blank worksheet, or insert a new blank worksheet.
6. Select cell A1 on the blank worksheet.
7. On the Ribbon's Home tab, click Paste.
8. Delete the sheet that contains the pasted copy of the pivot table.

Your custom PivotTable style now appears in the PivotTable Styles gallery,
in the new workbook.

**Excel version 2016**

Unfortunately, in Excel 2016 the above method does not work and the custom
pivot table style is not copied. The following method works in
Excel 2016 and also in Excel 2013.

1. Open the old workbook with the pivot table that has the custom style applied.
2. Open the new workbook where you want to add that custom style
3. Position the workbooks, so you can see the sheet tabs in both files
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and drag a copy of the pivot table sheet from the old workbook into the new workbook.
5. The custom style is now copied into the new workbook, and you can delete the sheet that you copied from the old workbook.

For more detailed information and screenshots see the article
[Excel Pivot Table Format - Copy Custom Style to Different File](http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-format.html#videocopyfile).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to right click on the tab that contains the pivot style you created and want to use.

1. Once you right click, select 'Move or Copy'.
2. Once you select that option, select the workbook you want this pivot table style in.
3. Select 'Move to End'.
4. Select 'Create Copy'.

This creates a copy to the other workbook and allows you to use your personal template style on any pivot table in the workbook.  If you click on the pivot table and go to the design tab at the top, you will now see your style available to use.  Once you have selected your created style, you can then delete the copy at the end of the workbook.